# How is this line modulation scheme called

Tags: encoding

It seems that a lot of cheap ASK transmitters (for remote controls, etc.) use a similar line encoding, an example can be seen here: [Reverse Engineering a wireless doorbell and performing a replay attack – Part1](https://www.devmire.com/2019/06/14/reverse-engineering-a-wireless-doorbell-and-performing-a-replay-attack-part1/). The one in this article can be described like that:

- 0 is sent as: high - low - low
- 1 is sent as: high - high - low

I'm currently trying to replay a wireless doorbell (different from the one described in the article) and it seems similar but not exactly the same:
[image: ASK signal]

I think that here:

- 0 is sent as: low - high - low
- 1 is sent as: high - high - low

So the signal in the screenshot can be interpreted as:
`001101010110011111`

I tried to look at some line encoding articles in wikipedia (Manchester code, NRZI, etc.) but I can't find an exact match.  How is this scheme called?

Comment: A popular scheme is "Manchester encoding" where the value of the bit is indicated by the transition from low-to-high or high-to-low mixed in with timing pulses.  I recommend you look up that reference and see if that matches your doorbell.

Comment: Do you know the contents of the message, before encoding? If not, it doesn't matter if its Manchester, NRZ, 8b/10b etc, inverted or not. If it's clearly ASK, and stays the same every time (not a rolling code), just sample it 10x faster than the shortest feature, and replay it. You only need to know more if you want a general method to synthesise a valid signal from (say) the known dip-switch settings on Tx or Rx.

Comment: Until the last sequence it could have been interpreted as Morse, EWAAWE. Sadly the last character .----- isn't valid. Perhaps your doorbell has a bad fist. Seriously, I agree with the previous comment, you would need to look at other message types to try to determine the encoding scheme beyond OOK. There's a tutorial in European GRCON (either 2021 or 2022) about how to approach this kind of decoding.